# Using InverseProperty in M to N relationships

Tags: entity-framework

Lets say a person can belong to several groups and a group can contain several persons.

 Also a person can administrate several groups and a group can be administrated by several persons.

How do I add some attribute (InverseProperty) to these properties so that they match correctly with each other?

```
public class Person
{
   public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Group> AdministratedGroups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
   public virtual ICollection<Person> Members { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Person> Administrators { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was pretty obvious at the end:

```
public class Person
{
   [InverseProperty("Members")]
   public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
   [InverseProperty("Administrators")]
   public virtual ICollection<Group> AdministratedGroups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
   [InverseProperty("Groups")]
   public virtual ICollection<Person> Members { get; set; }
   [InverseProperty("AdministratedGroups")]
   public virtual ICollection<Person> Administrators { get; set; }
}
```